# Implementation of Stream that wraps another stream

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, filestream, out-of-memory

Well i guess i ll have to make a trilogy related to the question of mine found at [Out of memory exception while loading images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853615/out-of-memory-exception-while-loading-images)

So here comes the second part.

According to the answers - comments found to the post mentioned above, sooner or later any computer will run out of memory while executing my code.  :(

But thanks to [Google](http://www.google.com) i found a way of applying [WrappingStream Implementation.](http://code.logos.com/blog/2009/05/wrappingstream_implementation.html) where according to the writer

> The BitmapImage keeps a reference to
>   the source stream (presumably so that
>   you can read the StreamSource property
>   at any time), so it keeps the
>   MemoryStream object alive.
>   Unfortunately, even though
>   MemoryStream.Dispose has been invoked,
>   it doesn't release the byte array that
>   the memory stream wraps. So, in this
>   case, bitmap is referencing stream,
>   which is referencing buffer, which may
>   be taking up a lot of space on the
>   large object heap. Note that there
>   isn't a true memory leak; when there
>   are no more references to bitmap, all
>   these objects will (eventually) be
>   garbage collected. But since bitmap
>   has already made its own private copy
>   of the image (for rendering), it seems
>   rather wasteful to have the
>   now-unnecessary original copy of the
>   bitmap still in memory.

So here are a couple of questions i have.
(And Before starting down-voting please keep in mind that i am a newbie!)

Could i use the WrappingStream class to avoid out of memory errors?
If the first one is true, how can i adopt it and make it work with my [example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853615/out-of-memory-exception-while-loading-images)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could i use the WrappingStream class to avoid out of memory errors?

No, it is aimed at a different problem.

Comment: I'll post a more useful answer to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

System.Net.Http.Formatting.Internal.DelegatingStream should fit the bill. Too bad Microsoft hasn't made this class public in the framework.

https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/4e40cdef9c8a8226685f95ef03b746bc8322aa92/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/Internal/DelegatingStream.cs